# Highcharts with AJAX graph generating

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, highcharts

Ive tried to implement AJAX into highcharts, but for some reason cannot get it working.

My HTML and javascript look like this:

```
function test () {
var options = {
    chart : {
        renderTo : 'container',
        type : 'spline',
        zoomType: 'x',
    },
    series : [{
            data: []
    }]
};

$.ajax({
        url : 'data.php?year=' + year,
        datatype : 'json',
        success : function () {
            options.series[0].setData(json['data']);
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        },
    });
}
```

The data.php output is:

```
{"name":2012,"data":[-1.4,-1.4,-1.3,-1.3,-1.3,-1.3,-1.3,-1.2,-1.3,-1.2,-1.2,-1.2]}
```

Any ideas what is wrong?

---

I changed it to this:
    function test () {
    var options = {
    chart : {
        renderTo : 'container',
        type : 'spline',
        zoomType: 'x',
    },
    series : [{
        data: [],
    }]
    };

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'data.php?year=' + year,
    datatype : 'json',
    success : function (json) {
        options.series[0].data = json;
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    },
});
}
```

but still I get no chart at all

Comment: Are you getting a blank graph or something??...which part it's not working??

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the data parameter for your success function.

```
    success : function () {
```

should be

```
    success : function(json) {
```

Right now `json` is undefined within that function.

Comment: .setData() doesn't exist either. `options` is just a plain object with no methods defined, unless that's something highcharts does in the background. maybe `options.series.data[0] = json['data']` instead?

Comment: function test () {
var options = {
    chart : {
        renderTo : 'container',
        type : 'spline',
        zoomType: 'x',
    },
    series : [{
  data: [],
 }]
};

$.ajax({
        url : 'data.php?year=' + year,
        datatype : 'json',
        success : function (json) {
            options.series.data[0] = json['data'];
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        },
    });
}

And still I get no graph generated at all, just no chart created.

Comment: so check your javascript control (shift-ctrl-k in FF) and see if any errors show up.

Comment: ok, partially there... now Im getting a blank chart... I am sure the problem is in the way the data is fetched into highcharts,

I checked again, so the main line is:
 options.series[0].data = json['data'];

And the output of data.php looks like:
{"name":2012,"data":[-1.4,-1.4,-1.3,-1.3,-1.3,-1.3,-1.3,-1.2,-1.3,-1.2,-1.2,-1.2]}

Answer (score 0):

In case when you load series object by json, you need to parse it to json (it is string) or return json in script. Morever if you get series object, you cannot assign it to the data object, so in your case you need to use `series: datajson`